# SSIS Update (Replace) record instead of append based on Primary Key

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I created an SSIS Pacakge that imports a monthly extract claims file. I have a simple Data Flow task, flat file to OLEDB Destination with a Derived column component in between used to generate a primary Key (based on a combination of 3 columns in the extract file).

What I would like to do if possible is have the SSIS package only import brand new records based on the primary key so that if there is a file that is being imported that contains a (generated) primary key that already exists in the destination table, then I would like the package to delete the existing record in the table and then add the new record from the current file being imported.

I know I could do this by having a staging table where I load the file and then using some sql queries (sp) to delete and add records to the table appropriately but I am trying to accomplish the import without needing to create a staging table because the table that I am currently populating, already is a staging table...

Is what I am trying to accomplish possible, using SSIS and only 1 destination table or will I need to create an additional staging table?

Comment: You want to look into [Lookup transformation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/implementing-lookup-logic-in-sql-server-integration-services/) for what you want to achieve. Also see [msdn blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/11/25/lookup-pattern-range-lookups.aspx) for an example.

Comment: To follow up with what Kin said, you can use a Lookup transformation along with an OLE DB command to do the delete...However, there are some issues with using that OLE DB Command (as Devin Knight mentions here http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dknight/2008/12/29/ssis-avoid-ole-db-command/ ).   Long story short, I am not sure your initial approach of loading to a staging table is a bad one, depending on your situation.  But it is certainly possible to do what you are wanting with these tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kin mentioned in his comment above, it is possible to accomplish what I was trying to do using the SSIS Lookup transformation component (example also provided in his comment) which answers my question.

While I will surely be using this component in the future I decided to go with a more straightforward SQL scripting method to accomplish what I needed after reading mskinner's comment (and referenced blog) which points out that using an Execute SQL task is probably going to be much faster/efficient than using the Lookup Transformation component in SSIS for what I am trying to accomplish.